# Setting layouts for each tabhost from info passed from previous activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, textview

I am having some trouble setting up my tabbed layouts. My aim is to take some information passed from the previous activity, in this case "siteName", and during onCreate set this information as a text field in one of my the tabs.

Currently I am getting nullPointer exception and can only figure out how to set values in the overall layout, in this case "location_tabbed_menu" and not in the individual tabs.

I have searched around for a few hours but am unable to find the answer. My code is as follows:

```
public class LocationTabbedMenu extends TabActivity {
TextView title;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location_tabbed_menu);



    //Get passed information
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String siteName = i.getStringExtra("name");



    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Photos
    TabSpec infospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Info");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    infospec.setIndicator("Info", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_tabbed_menu_info_icon));
    Intent infoIntent = new Intent(this, LocationTabbedMenuInfo.class);

    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTest);
    title.setText(siteName);

    infospec.setContent(infoIntent);

    // Tab for Songs
    TabSpec foodspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Food");
    foodspec.setIndicator("Songs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_tabbed_menu_food_icon));
    Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, LocationTabbedMenuFood.class);
    foodspec.setContent(songsIntent);

    // Tab for Videos
    TabSpec tipsspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tips");
    tipsspec.setIndicator("Videos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_tabbed_menu_tips_icon));
    Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, LocationTabbedMenuTips.class);
    tipsspec.setContent(videosIntent);

    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(infospec); 
    tabHost.addTab(foodspec); 
    tabHost.addTab(tipsspec); 
}
}
```

Please note that the value "testText" is the id of a textview within a single tab.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that something may be amiss with the initial layout. [Remember that the names 'tabhost', 'tabs', and 'tabcontent' must be used for the TabHost, TabWidget and FrameLayout respectively.] Another possibility is that the referenced activities do not exist or are not referenced in your manifest. Also, I don't see a reference to an 'onTabChangeListener'. That is where you would get the first peek at the tab identifier: Info, Food or Tips.